# Using brackets / ellipsis in quotes; also, citing poems?

Tags: poetry, ellipses, citation, square-brackets

When using a bracketed form of ellipsis, would I also bracket the period at the end of a quote ended early?

Ex.

> "What god drove them to fight with such a fury? / Apollo the son of Zeus and Leto. Incensed at the king / he swept a fatal plague through the army-men were dying / and all because Agamemnon spurned Apollo's priest. / Yes, Chryses approached the Achaeans' fast ships / to win his daughter back, bringing a priceless ransom / and bearing high in hand, wound on a golden staff, / the wreaths of the god, the distant deadly Archer."

Would(?) be:

> "What god drove them to fight with such a fury? / Apollo [...] / Yes, Chryses approached the Achaeans' fast ships / to win his daughter back[.]"

And I were to shorten two lines within this poem, would I also use dual ellipsis, even back to back?

> "What god drove them to fight with such a fury? / Apollo [...] / [...] Chryses approached the Achaeans' fast ships / to win his daughter back[.]"

And if I do, would I still use two ellipsis when quoting in the original format?

> "What god drove them to fight with such a fury?
> Apollo [...]
> [...] Chryses approached the Achaeans' fast ships
> to win his daughter back[.]"

I have also seen poems sometimes quoted by (Title, Book, Line Numbers), ex. *(Iliad 1.9-16)*, but haven't seen this method identified in any style guide. What exactly is the name of this citation format, and when is it proper (or improper) to use this citing style?

Comment: On question #1, does the reader need to know how much you skipped and what punctuation you are not showing? Rules must serve logic, and I'll die on that hill.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Do they? If it's purely up to personal style, then I would say that it's not necessarily important, but I would assume that if I am bracketing the ellipses to avoid confusion / add clarity to the edited portion of the quote (which I do prefer to do), that I may also bracket the period at the end, when applicable, just for consistency sake.

Comment: What style guide are you using? Have you checked what is says?

Comment: This will probably sound silly, but I'm not using any particular style guide (I'm not writing an academic paper, or in a professional setting, so there isn't any set guidelines on what style I should follow). I've checked some style guides for the above questions, MLA, Oxford, and APA, to name a few, but they didn't provide any / any clear answers for the above. Both Oxford and APA say brackets are not necessary for ellipsis, and MLA says their inclusion is optional, but they don't say anything on whether a period would then thus be also bracketed, if one is bracketing the ellipses.

Comment: A lack of explanation, I could assume then, mean that it wouldn't be necessary. The other questions also depend on the style guide, or are just not seemingly included / explained; but I suppose I was wondering if there might be any general grammar rules that could address the above, not tied to a particular style.

Comment: Your formatting is unhelpful here, because what Markdown does doesn't necessarily match the input. To separate lines without including a blank line, you need to add two spaces on the end. You have _written_ the first examples as separate lines, but they are all mashed together in the output. Which did you intend? For the last example, you can eliminate the blank lines and join all the separate quotes together by adding the two spaces to the end of each line (and taking out the empty line itself).

Comment: I intended it to be read as it appeared in the output; also, thanks.

Comment: I'd lose the slashes. Ellipsis (three points in brackets) just means missing text. If you want two sets of them, that is your choice but there is probably no need for them.

Answer (score 1):

We do not normally put brackets around ellipses.

We do not normally break an ellipsis into 2 to put other punctuation. Just leave out the punctuation just like you leave out the text.

We do not normally supply our own punctuation to replace the punctuation that we have elided. But if we do, we put it in brackets.

Thus, in your example, I would write: ""What god drove them to fight with such a fury? / Apollo ... Yes, Chryses approached the Achaeans' fast ships / to win his daughter back ..."

If I was cutting the poem down this much, I'd probably also leave out the slash line-breaks, as they cease to be meaningful in a diced up excerpt.

If I felt it needed the period, I'd write, "... to win his daughter back[.]"

I suppose if the original had ellipses, then without brackets or some other notation it could be unclear whether the ellipses represent your elision or are from the original. But then, you'd have a similar problem if the original include square brackets. Suggest some alternative punctuation and one could always say, What if the original had that punctuation? If it really matters, include a note to explain. Like I often see quotes followed by a note like "(Italics in the original.)"

Comment: So in the case of the final example, if I were to write the quote in its original format, would I also not include the second ellipses?

Comment: Correct. That amounts to putting two ellipses in a row, which is unnecessary.